# How to capture checkbox event in directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm newbie to Angular and wanted to invoke and capture Checkbox event `(checked/unchecked)` in a directive. So what that means is when someone checks the checkbox, it should invoke some code/function in either `links|controller`; ideally in a controller of a directive to avoid using $watch. Below is what I got so far:

```
<!-- this reside in a different view under some controller called 'myCtrl' -->
<input my-directive type="checkbox">  

angular.module('myApp').directive('myDirective', function () {

   var directive = {};

   directive.restrict = 'A';

   directive.controller = ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
        // maybe capture checkbox event here

   }];

   directive.compile = function () {

       var linkingFunction = function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

       // or capture event here and do some logic 
       // logic might look like below in pseudo code
       if (input element is checked ) {
           do something 
           also store the capture value in a variable i.e. `checked`
       } 

       if (input is uncheched) {
           then do this other thing 
           also store the capture value in a variable i.e. `unchecked`
       } 
       };

       return linkingFunction;
   };

   return directive;
});
```

Ideally, I want to invoke this directive with every `checked and unchecked` event, and also capture the event value, but the main concern is to invoke this directive when checkbox is checked.

Can someone tell me how can that be done?

Comment: why don't think of `watcher` on `ngModel` inside directive?

Comment: @Simple-Solution, what you are trying to do is definitely not a simple solution

Answer (score 0):

The directive you are trying to do is already existing and is called [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Just set it to your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-change="yourController.reactOnChangedValue($event)">
```

Check the given URL, they have an example which should be enough for your purposes.

If you still insist on writing it on your own, just look at [ng-change source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js). Just adapt it for your needs.

Comment: I always like to note that on checkboxes I have noticed ng-change to be hit or miss so if you run into trouble you can try ng-click.